# How do I start an existing node.js backend on Microsoft Azure Web Apps?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure and currently host my node.js backend at another cloud provider, and I want to understand the steps I need to make in order to host it at Azure, without using Visual Studio Code.

It is a very easy question, yet it seems impossible to find an answer to.

I've seen the 5mins quick starts here;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs

But in the guide, the site is directly deployed to the web URL;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs#browse-to-the-app

But none of them explains the fundamentals on how Azure runs the process.

How does Azure start my backend app? Where do I configure that, what is needed?

That's not mentioned in the guide at all.

Is there a guide for what exactly what files are required and how to configure them in order to start my backend?

Microsoft Azure feels like a black box right now, any documentation is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start an existing node.js backend on Microsoft Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948480/how-do-i-start-an-existing-node-js-backend-on-microsoft-azure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, you need to configure `web.config` if you want to run nodejs app on the Azure.

I followed this sample node.js app: [nodejs-docs-hello-world](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world) and deploy it to Azure. It works fine,you could refer to `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web> 
    <compilation batch="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="scripts.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="scripts.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I suggest you navigating to the `KUDU` url: `https://<your app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and go to `site\wwwroot` to upload your files so that the files are contained within a directory.

Or discard zip deploy temporarily, just drag the local files directly to the `d:home\site\wwwroot` directory.

[image]